# ibex40 pdf stream to PDF file?

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf

I have a memory stream that holds pdf data after "generate" function:

```
        ibex4.licensing.Generator.setRuntimeKey(ibexKey);

        //Creat an instance of PDF document
        FODocument doc = new FODocument(); 

        //Load in-memory xml to stream 
        MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();         //create an empty stream first
        xml.Save(xmlStream);                                 //save xml to the stream
        xmlStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                 //position stream at the beggining

        //create xslt stream
        MemoryStream xsltStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(physicalXSLTPath));

        //create pdf stream
        MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream();

        doc.generate(xmlStream, xsltStream, pdfStream, false);
```

I need to store pdf stream to a file (using FODocument somhow -  ibex 40 API?) so that a user can download it.

---

### **How do I do that?**

Maybe my xml or xslt is not formatted well but I doubt as I have included xml version to both xml and xslt file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like new version of ibex (for .NET 4.0) called ibex4 is using different namespaces then older versions. I will post an example about how I solved this if there is enough time in the future.